# Error Launching Cloud Foundry Plugin in STS and GGTS (Linux, 64 bit)

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm trying to use the latest cloudfoundry plugin and getting 'Failed to create the part's controls'.  I've tried on STS 64 bit, GGTS 32 and 64 to no avail (all on a Linux 64 bit machine).

Any ideas?  This is the exception that is display when I double click on the SpringSource Cloud Foundry Server in the Servers tab.

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: assertion failed: 
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:96)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.setActivePage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:362)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:129)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:95)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:300)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:857)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:837)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:111)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:318)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:240)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:141)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:889)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:623)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:725)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:690)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:675)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1042)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:67)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4291)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:187)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:57)
at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:418)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:385)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:578)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:314)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:962)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3071)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$21(WorkbenchPage.java:2996)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2978)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2974)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2933)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2916)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.ServerUIPlugin.editServer(ServerUIPlugin.java:439)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.ServerUIPlugin.editServer(ServerUIPlugin.java:422)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.view.servers.OpenAction.perform(OpenAction.java:36)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.view.servers.AbstractServerAction.run(AbstractServerAction.java:64)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:221)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$3.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:185)
at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:866)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:864)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1152)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:462)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1256)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:269)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3554)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3179)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you give some more information to help narrow down what might be causing the issue?

1. Distribution and version of Linux. Ubuntu 10.0.4, 12.0.4, etc. The SWT libraries are different, and newer versions of Linux using Gnome 3 may not be as stable and robust as older versions.
2. Can you verify which version of the Cloud Foundry plugin is installed?
3. Open the Eclipse Error Log, clear it, attempt to open the CF editor by double-clicking on the Cloud Foundry server instance in the Servers View and see if there are any other exceptions are thrown aside from the one you already posted.
4. See if the error also occurs when opening the tc server editor. If possible, double-click on the default tc server instance that appears in the Servers view, or create one. To create one:

   - Right-click on the Server View
   - Select New -> Server
   - In the wizard, under VMware, select "VMware vFabric tc Server...", click Next
   - Select "Create new instance", click Next
   - Enter a name and select any of the templates, click Finish
   - Once the tc server instance is created in the Servers View, double click on it to open the editor

Comment: Just following up, were you able to get the Cloud Foundry plugin working?

Comment: I don't know if this is similar enough to help narrow it down or not, but I'm getting a similar exception (an NPE at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyShowView(WorkbenchPage.java:1204) also inside org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:129). Maybe compatibility isn't so compatible?

Window x64, Juno, AJDT 2.2.1e42x-20120724-1900, and CompatibilityPart is in org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.103.0.v20120530-1824.jar

Too bad I can't post the stacktrace in a comment.

Comment: And if the loss of formatting makes it unclear -- the similarity is STS code being called from CompatiblityPart.createPartControl(), and at least his and my line numbers are the same there -- likely similar environments.

Not a lot, I realize, but maybe something jumps out at you -- or not.

Comment: And a little earlier, in the log, I find this.

org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Recursive reference trying to create class org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:275)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:240)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)

Comment: Mine looks to be related to this:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=377343

which is fixed for Juno SR1.

Given that, I don't think we have the same problem -- but perhaps my environment info will be of help. Or maybe this will help the next person with my problem, whom Google deposits here!

But do check your error log.